# SVN KIT commit comments issue

Tags: java, svnkit

I am using SVNKIT to commit changes in SVN. it is running fine as expected in java. problem is comments are not being saved in svn.
i am doing something like below:

```
String comment = "testing here";
ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor(comment, null /*locks*/ , false /*keepLocks*/ , null /*mediator*/ );
SVNCommitInfo commitInfo = modifyFile(editor, "", "filePath", contents, modifiedContents);
```

and modifyFile methos is like below

```
 private static SVNCommitInfo modifyFile(ISVNEditor editor, String dirPath,
            String filePath, byte[] oldData, byte[] newData) throws SVNException {

        editor.openRoot(-1);
        editor.openDir(dirPath, -1);
        editor.openFile(filePath, -1);
        editor.applyTextDelta(filePath, null);
        SVNDeltaGenerator deltaGenerator = new SVNDeltaGenerator();
        String checksum = deltaGenerator.sendDelta(filePath, new ByteArrayInputStream(oldData), 0, new ByteArrayInputStream(newData), editor, true);

        editor.closeFile(filePath, checksum);
        editor.closeDir();
        editor.closeDir();

        return editor.closeEdit();
    }
```

i am not able to find the mistake as to why comments are not being saved. maven entry for same is -

```
<groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.11</version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, thanks to one of my intelligent teammate, i found the solution. there seems to be a bug in 1.8.11 version and it doesn't allow comments to be saved.
i changed the version in pom.xml to 1.7.5 and it works like anything.

No change in code was done. might be helpful to others who are struggling with same issue

Comment: I had this problem as well, and at first it did not seem to help to downgrade to 1.7.5 because i was using grab() inside a groovy script run by a jenkins pipline using load().
Changing the pipeline to use sh() and run the groovy script stand alone helped.

Answer (score 0):

From SVNKIT 1.8.9 onwards there is support for ephemeral transactional properties of Subversion1.8 [Refer https://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.8/group__Capabilities.html#gae1424ec62e198a77499726431c35ab6e] which is causing the problem. So using any SVNKIT version prior to 1.8.9 should not give this error. Refer https://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/branches/1.8.x/CHANGES.txt to know about changes made in SVNKIT over multiple version